# strange behaviour of std::aligned_storage

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, alignment

```
_declspec(align(32)) struct St{ 
    int foo; 
};
typedef std::aligned_storage<sizeof(St), std::alignment_of<St>::value>::type Ta;

int main() {
    std::cout << std::alignment_of<St>::value << '\n'; 
    std::cout << std::alignment_of<Ta>::value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
32
8
```

I'm using msvc(visual studio 2012). Is `Ta` aligned by 32, or just 8?

Comment: Could you add the visual-studio-20xx tag that corresponds to your version of the compiler please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With VS2012 `max_align_t` is 8, which means the maximum alignment supported in all contexts is 8. Alignments larger than this value are 'extended alignments' and

> It is implementation-defined whether any extended alignments are supported and the contexts in which they are supported.
>
> — *[basic.align] 3.11/3*

Microsoft's alignment specifier permits extended alignments, however they are not supported by the implementation of the standard library they are using. Although this doesn't seem to be non-conformant it does seem like a QoI issue to me.

Answer (score 2):

I translated your example into standard C++11 by substituting `struct alignas(32) St{` for `_declspec(align(32)) struct St{`.

I then ran it on my system (clang++ / libc++) OS X.  My results are:

```
32
32
```

If I change 32 to 16 or 64 I continue to get the same alignment for both `St` and `Ta`.  I suspect this is a bug in the implementation you're using.

Comment: It seems that alignas is not supported in vs. Thank you for pointing that out.